# Mesos - dynamic cluster size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mesos, autoscaling

Is it possible in Mesos to have dynamic cluster size - with total cluster CPU and RAM quotas set?

Mesos knows my AWS credentials and spawns new ec2 instances only if there is a new job that cannot fit into existing resources. (AWS or other cloud provider). Similar to that - when the job is finished it could kill the ec2 instance.

It can be Mesos plugin/framework or some external tool - any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we are doing is we are using Mesos monitoring tools and HTTP endpoints @ http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/endpoints/ to monitor the cluster.

We have our own framework that gets all the relevant information from the master and slave nodes and our algorithm uses that information to scale the cluster.

For example if the cluster CPU utilization is > 0.90 we bring up a new instance and register that slave to master.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you are looking for a solution to autoscale your Mesos cluster?

What some people will do on AWS for example is to create an [autoscaling group](https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) allowing them to scale up and down the number of agents/slave nodes depending on their needs.
Note that the trigger when to scale up/down are usually application dependent (e.g., could be ok for one app to be at a 100% utilization while for others 80% should already trigger a scale-up action).

For an example of using the AWS auto scaling groups you could have a look at [Mesosphere DCOS Community edition](https://mesosphere.com/amazon/setup/) (note as mentioned above you will still have to write the trigger code for scaling your scaling group).

Comment: This partially answers my question, I just would like the autoscaling trigger in a different place. Not to scale cluster for existing jobs, but for new ones. So the scenario is as follows: I create a job that requires 10 CPUs, Mesos has only 5 available, but Mesos knows that it can still create 10 EC2 instances, so it creates one with 8 CPUs and assigns some of them to my task.

Comment: What you could do is write an app checking the cluster utilization (Mesos Metrics) and new deployments (Marathon API) and in the above scenario scale the ec2 autoscaling group (ec2 API).. See https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-autoscale for an example of autoscaling applicatons....

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the Mesos can not autoscaling itself; it need someone to start Mesos Agent for the cluster. One option is to build a script and be managed by Marathon, this script is to start/stop agents after comparing your pending tasks in the framework and Mesos cluster.